# Change mouse location of remote computer using powerhsell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, invoke-command

I am writing a script to change the location of the mouse of a remote computer. The computer or computers would be on the same LAN and per GPO have remote PS sessions/commands enabled.

I have it working on my computer but when I try to run it remotely it does not move the mouse.

```
    Invoke-Command -computername remote computer -ScriptBlock
{
while($true)
{
$rand = Get-Random -Maximum 5 -Minimum -5
   $a = [windows.forms.cursor]::Position.y + $rand
   $b = [windows.forms.cursor]::Position.x + $rand

   [Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = "$b, $a"

  Start-sleep -s .5

   $rand = Get-Random -Maximum 5 -Minimum -5
   $a = [windows.forms.cursor]::Position.y - $rand
   $b = [windows.forms.cursor]::Position.x - $rand

  [Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = "$b, $a"

   Start-sleep -s .5
}
}
```

I have a feeling it may be related to the system.windows.forms assembly but I am not sure of a solution.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with PowerShell at all. What is the purpose of such a script?

Comment: When you run a command remotely, PowerShell does not have a full login session with GUI and everything - so there is no mouse to manipulate. That's also quite an odd thing to do with PS and there's probably a much better solution for whatever you want to do. So why don't you tell us?

Comment: The goal in the script was random movement so I could get it to work. But the end goal was to gain a better understanding of working with peripherals on remote computers, how well it would work that sort of thing. At my work we have various exterior accessories and before trying to work with them in adjusting settings and movement I wanted to work with something seemingly simple like a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

In a remote session this will not be possible, as your session does not have a GUI /Handle to operate on.

On your local machine running in your host, you have a GUI and the handle so calls for System.Windows.Forms / Cursor works.

If you really want to do this, you could wrap this into a script and execute it with a tool that allows you to interact with the desktop.

Take a look at PSExec - with the "-i" parameter for interactive.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx